# I need to move every other row up in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table of information, but each item is across 2 rows.

So what should be 1 line-item is in `A1` and `A`2, `A3` and `A4`, `A5` and `A6`, etc.

How can I move

- `A2` to `B1`,
- `A4` to `B3`,
- `A6` to `B5`

etc?

Thanks so much...Every time you help me you save a kitten!

Comment: Insert a column ahead of (to left of) Column A, and delete row 1.

Comment: In cell B1 use a formula like `=IF(MOD(ROW(A2),2)=0,A2,"")`.

Comment: Lol, same formula posted as answer at the same time as my comment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In B1:

```
=IF(MOD(ROW(),2)=1,A2,"")
```

Fill down, copy--> paste values and sort on ColB to bring the data together.  Delete the "spare" rows.

Comment: Thanks so much! now is there a quick way to delete the spare row?

Comment: The sorting should bring the "moved" data to the top of the block, leaving all the "spare" rows so you can delete them in one shot...

Answer (score 0):

You can automate deleting the spare rows too, I have a similar function like this:

Dim r As Range, rows As Long, i As Long

```
Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("whatever your range is")
rows = r.rows.Count
For i = rows To 1 Step (-1)
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(r.rows(i)) = 0 Then r.rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
    Next
```